# How do I use layouts from PUG-Bootstrap?

Tags: node.js, express, npm, pug

I am using pug for the first time and am trying to figure out how to use npm pug-bootstrap so I can use their layouts.

I npm installed jade-bootstrap and pug-bootstrap but cannot find in the documentation how to reference their cover bootstrap layout in my index.pug file.

I already have my server.js file and can render html onto my local port. I tried copying the cover.pug page into my index.pug page but that does not work.

I'm assuming I have to call it but I dont know how. How can I call my layouts from PUG-Bootstrap?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score 4):

First remove **jade-bootstrap** or **pug-bootstrap** packages:

***npm remove jade-bootstrap***

***npm remove pug-bootstrap***

**Jade** was deprecated, now instead of jade it's called **PUG**

Install pug:

***npm install pug --save***

use **--save** if you want to install pug only to your project folder, if you will execute command without **--save** , package will be installed globally to you station.

Enter http://html2jade.org

Now you can create simple bootstrap html page and it will be converted to your noted pug file.

For example, If you need to *include footer.pug to your index.pug* .

In index pug put absolute path to footer.pug (**includes/foot.pug**)

References:

[Include pugJs](https://pugjs.org/language/includes.html)

Comment: html2jade.org is the best thing i've ever seen.  Saved me hours.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better way but this is what I did to access Bootstrap CSS from my pug templates:

First, installed bootstrap via npm:

```
npm install bootstrap
```

This downloads and installs the bootstrap JavaScript and CSS locally on your server.  I then copied the two folders out of dist to the public location on my server, i.e.:

```
{server directory}\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js
{server directory}\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css
```

into:

```
{server directory}\public\js
{server directory}\public\css
```

Then in my layout.pug template, simply added:

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/bootstrap.min.css')
```

(I added the second line).

There may be a cleaner way, but this is what worked for me.

Comment: This removes the whole purpose of a package manager. You might aswell use CDN's then.

Comment: Not only did you not use a CDN... You retrieved the bootstrap css file by installing bootstrap with npm. Try `curl -O https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css` OR `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">`